# How do I display StringLabelValue?

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I'm use `Teechart` version `.Net & VS2005`.

`X-axis` of the graph type of date and time, `Y-axis` was added to the Point Series.

I want to show the `StringLabelValue`.

**My Code :**

```
private void GridPoint()
{
    datatable dt_point = new datatable();

    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points Pinpoint = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Points();
    TChart1.Series.Add(Pinpoint);

    Pinpoint.Pointer.Visible = false;
    Pinpoint.Pointer.InflateMargins = false;
    Pinpoint.Pointer.Transparency = 100;
    Pinpoint.Pointer.Pen.Visible = false;
    Pinpoint.Marks.Color = Color.White;
    Pinpoint.Marks.Pen.Color = Color.White;
    Pinpoint.Marks.Shadow.Visible = false;
    Pinpoint.Marks.Visible = true;

    Steema.TeeChart.Axis axis = new Steema.TeeChart.Axis();
    TChart1.Axes.Custom.Add(axis);

    axis.StartPosition = 9;
    axis.EndPosition = 9;

    axis.Labels.Items.Add(0, " ");
    axis.Labels.Items.Add(2000, " ");
    axis.Labels.Items[0].Visible = false;
    axis.Labels.Items[1].Visible = false;

    axis.Title.Caption = "";
    axis.Title.Font.Color = Color.Black;

    TChart1.Series[0].CustomVertAxis = axis;
    TChart1.Series[0].Clear();

    if (dt_Point.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        dt_Point.Columns.Add("SetTime", typeof(DateTime));
        dt_Point.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));
        dt_Point.Columns.Add("Label", typeof(string));
    }

    DataRow row;
    row = dt_Point.NewRow();
    row["SetTime"] = "2012-08-02 18:14:24";
    row["Value"] = 100;
    row["Label"] = "Point";
    dt_Point.Rows.Add(row);

    TChart1.Series[0].XValues.DataMember = "SetTime";
    TChart1.Series[0].YValues.DataMember = "Value";
    TChart1.Series[0].DataMember = "Label";
    TChart1.Series[0].DataSource = dt_Point;
}
```

**show the Graph :**

[image]

**I want to show graph:** 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you set `XValues.DateTime` to `true` and change the `DateTimeFormat` and `Style` of the Bottom Axis labels to achieve the result that you want:

```
//XValues as DateTimeValues.
Pinpoint.XValues.DateTime = true;

//Labels axes style and format 
tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "hh:mm:ss";
tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Style = AxisLabelStyle.Value;
```